# Error LNK2019 al usar la función timeGetTime() de la API Win32

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en C++, y usando "Visual Studio 2019" he escrito el código siguiente:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long tiempo() {
    return timeGetTime();
}

int main(){

    long milisegundos = tiempo();

    printf("\n* Tiempo: %ld", milisegundos);

    return 0;
}
```

Pero al compilarlo me sale en la lista de errores:

```
Error   LNK1120 1 externos sin resolver

Error   LNK2019 símbolo externo __imp_timeGetTime sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la 
        función "long __cdecl tiempo(void)" (?tiempo@@YAJXZ)
```

No entiendo porqué es así, ni cómo corregirlo, aunque es un código muy simple, en otros proyectos he podido usar sin problemas otras funciones de la API de Windows, y no he cambiado la configuración del editor de código.

Comment: [Su documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timegettime) indica que dicha función está en la librería de importación `Winmm.lib`. ¿ La estás incluyendo ?